# 0 Columns in DataGrid When i use DefaultView

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Hello i am trying to hide columns in a DataGrid from a DefaultView but it give me 0 columns.

Code:

```
productsTableAdapter pta = new productsTableAdapter();
pta.Fill(dataset.products);
productsDataTable pdta = pta.GetDataByInvoiceID(invoiceID);
InvoiceProductsDataGrid.ItemsSource = pdta.DefaultView;

InvoiceProductsDataGrid.Columns[0].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
InvoiceProductsDataGrid.Columns[4].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
InvoiceProductsDataGrid.Columns[5].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
InvoiceProductsDataGrid.Columns[6].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
InvoiceProductsDataGrid.Columns[7].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
InvoiceProductsDataGrid.Columns[8].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
InvoiceProductsDataGrid.Columns[10].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
InvoiceProductsDataGrid.Columns[11].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
InvoiceProductsDataGrid.Columns[12].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
InvoiceProductsDataGrid.Columns[13].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

Comment: Are you sure pdta is returning one or more rows?

Comment: yes it give's me data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @trapspring, it sounds like `pdta` comes back empty. In which case, something like this could come in handy.

```
int[] colsToHide = { 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13 };
int pointer = 0;

//Hide for as long as the desired column index exists
//Which means the order you put the indices in colsToHide
//DOES affect the results of the while loop.
while (colsToHide[pointer] < InvoiceProductsDataGrid.Columns.Count)
{
    InvoiceProductsDataGrid.Columns[colsToHide[pointer]].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

Comment: i need to hide the relations but i can't the the default view returns me 0 columns at 'InvoiceProductsDataGrid.ItemsSource'

Comment: The question is that i am returning a DataView and i don't know how to hide columns from a DataView and from a DataRowView

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was, that i was trying to hide something that i havd to remove and the code is this

```
productsTableAdapter pta = new productsTableAdapter();
pta.Fill(dataset.products);
productsDataTable pdta = pta.GetDataByInvoiceID(invoiceID);

pdta.Columns.Remove("client_id");
pdta.Columns.Remove("id1");
pdta.Columns.Remove("units");
pdta.Columns.Remove("provider");
pdta.Columns.Remove("sub_categorie");
pdta.Columns.Remove("id_invoice");
pdta.Columns.Remove("id_product");
pdta.Columns.Remove("invoice_date");
pdta.Columns.Remove("collection_method");
InvoiceProductsDataGrid.ItemsSource = pdta.DefaultView;
```